# Vue js bind a href but it doesn't go to the website url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I have a problem what I can't solve.
I want when you click on the website name that it goes to the website.
I want when the new tab open that de url of the website only is and not the

`http://localhost:8080/InternshipDetails/www.gameshop-twente.nl`.

[Image of the text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn2PM.png)

Here under is the url before you click on the website link:

[this is the url before you click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tqH9.png)

And here is after you clicked on the a href link:

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOSPX.png)

The data is coming from the Firebase database.
Here is my code what I have:

```
<p class="font-weight-bold">Website:</p>
<a :href="item.website" target="_blank">{{item.website}}</a>
```

Comment: What if you specify full url `http://www.gameshop-twente.nl` in `item.website` ? You can change `item` object so it contains `title` and `url`.

Comment: from `www.gameshop-twente.nl` to `https://gameshop-twente.nl`

Comment: @JózefPodlecki it work thanks!!

Comment: @MoloF it works I did not know this thank you so much!